# TypeError: Cannot read eager loaded property of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, eager-loading

I can eager load value with laravel like this `$comments = Comment::with(['replies', 'user'])->get();`, pass it to vue and display it, but then error message shows up:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined"
```

my template look like this:

```
<template><li>
    {{comment.user.avatar}}
</li></template>
```

however if I try to put it in image src, no error show, but everything disappears and looks like this in DOM

```
<li data-v-5ca803bb="">
    <!---->
</li>
```

The data exists in vue dev tools, I also tried with `<a href="{{comments.user.avatar}}"></a>`
and it didn't work, I don't know why I can't put it in any attribute

The comment object:

```
{"id":4,
"user_id":1,
"textField":"oiuio",
"created_at":"2019-11-06 10:52:10",
"updated_at":"2019-11-06 10:52:10",
"replies":[],
"user":{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Dominykas",
    "email":"s@gmail.com",
    "avatar":"https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Cute-Girl-Images.jpg",
    "provider":"google",
    "provider_id":"11185022391312255843258",
    "email_verified_at":null,
    "created_at":"2019-11-05 22:18:24",
    "updated_at":"2019-11-05 22:18:24"
}}
```

Comment: nah, it's singular, I better change it  and provide data object

Comment: try `dd(comment)` and check whether it have `user` value.

Comment: unfortunately, it does

Comment: user is not available with the comment. check the comment.user

Comment: if I display `{{comment.user}}` I get no errors only an array, If I display `{{comment.user.avatar}}` I get value, also mentioned error

Comment: Also I can't use that value as mentioned

Comment: do you use loop for iterating `$comments`?

Comment: Yeah, I loop in parent component and then pass singular instance in new child component.

Comment: check all the `comments` in the collection has `user`?

Comment: I just tried to have static variable like so `data(){return{ src: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/51/04/545104ed5f91a931e85f2be92048fd9f.jpg"} }` but unfortunately, I can't pass even that to html attributes (`src` or `href`) I get the same Dom response `<!---->`

Comment: @ab_ I checked, every single instance had one

Comment: However I'll do some digging and comeback later with solutions, maybe it's my flawed code, My comment component also consists on replied comments, which may not have same instances, I better separate concerns just to be sure

Comment: I itterated, Indeed, nested comments didn't had the same instances, I removed them and error was gone, how ever I still can't pass many data to html attributes, but for now probably be better to open new question because this question is answered ( why I got an error)

Comment: Indeed, I won't have to open anything, I had to do `:src=""` instead of "src={{}}" thaks for help

Comment: Comment does not have a user? show us your controller

Comment: `public function index()
    {
        $comments = Comment::with(['replies', 'user'])->get();
        return response()->json([
            'comments'    => $comments
        ], 200);
    }`

Comment: It does have, it was because I had same component in itself. The nested component didn't had user instance. My provided template isn't how it is actually in in my code, I combined separate concerns in one template and I provided bad  minimal code reprication of error. Now I know what's wrong with the help of people and will provide full report of error when I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wasn't able to put anything to attributes like so:

```
<img src="{{comments.user.avatar}}"></img>
```

because Vue works different from what I was used with react, syntax is actually:

```
<img :src="comments.user.avatar"></img>
```

Secondary, I had type error because indeed, I was missing user instance as people pointed out, however it was not in provided template example but in my spaghetti code.

Suggestion: better separate concerns and create few different components than try to use one and set flags everywhere and get errors like this, watch out.